# Fitting exponential curve with three parameters to some sample points.

Tags: exponential-function

[image]

I've been trying to solve this problem for days without involving a stat program or anything similar (including least squares fitting) but I've been unsuccessful. I attempted to substitute the given points, form three equations but I couldn't solve them. How do I get around this problem? In advance thank you for your help.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350754/fitting-exponential-curve-to-data) answers the question without the constant $C$, and gives a reference for the general case.

Comment: Do you want the curve equation or do you want how the values are obtained?

Comment: @NoChance, both would be fine but I believe J.G. has answered my question below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $B:=Ae^{-14k},\,t:=e^{-5k}$ so $B+C=9176,\,Bt^{11}+C=7681,\,Bt^{13}+C=7542$ and $B(1-t^{11})=1495,\,Bt^{11}(1-t^2)=139$. Hence $1495t^{13}-1634t^{11}+139=0$. The [only root](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+1495t%5E13-1634t%5E11%2B139%3D0+on+%280%2C+1%29) in $(0,\,1)$ is $t=0.9082$. Now use$$k=-\frac15\ln t,\,\left(\begin{array}{c}
B\\
C
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1\\
t^{11} & 1
\end{array}\right)^{-1}\left(\begin{array}{c}
9176\\
7681
\end{array}\right),\,A=Bt^{-2.8}.$$

Comment: It is not clear to me how did you find $x=e^{-5k}$. Thanks.

Comment: @NoChance That was a poor choice of name on my part for the variable; I've changed it to $t$. All I really did was change to a more convenient variable for comparing the differences between data.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, good answer.

Comment: Many thanks for your solution, however, I believe the first equation on the second line in incorrect.

Comment: @MeghanC Thanks; fixed.

Comment: One more question, why choose a value of t between 0 and 1?

Comment: @MeghanC Increasing $x$ reduces $y$, so you'll need $t$ in that range unless $A<0$.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense.